# i've found this message on the homepage of my wordpress website and pages return 404 not found

Tags: php, wordpress

This message [home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwQgP.png) appears on the homepage of the website and even when i try to access the wp-admin returns 404 not found.
i've tried to remove the wp-config.php file and add new one and also still the same problem.

Comment: Sounds like you've been hacked. Time to change all your passwords and check for bad plugins etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a whole page of common errors: https://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors

Your error is different from typical WordPress errors, I would tend to agree with the comment above that you've been hacked. In that link I posted, there is a section called "Compromised Website" that has instructions for scanning your site, and then instructions for if it's been hacked. That might be a good place to start! Good luck.